# [Expect Script]Separate log files for each device

Tags: expect, cisco, logfile, juniper-network-connect

My code is generated for one log file output from multiple devices.

How could we separate each device for each log file output?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#Slurp up the input file
set fp [open "ip.txt" r]
# To avoid empty lines, 'nonewline' flag is used
set file_data [read -nonewline $fp]
close $fp
set prompt ">"
log_file -noappend router_status.txt
foreach ip [split $file_data "\n"] {
    puts "Router $ip Interface Status"
    spawn telnet $ip
    expect "Username:"
    send "username\r"
    expect "assword:"
    send "password\r"
    expect $prompt
    # To avoid sending 'Enter' key on huge configurations
    send "show interface description\r"
    expect {
    -ex "---(more" { send -- " "; exp_continue }
    "*>" { send "exit\r" }
    }
    set timeout 3; # Reverting to default timeout
    # Sending 'exit' at global level prompt will close the connection
    expect eof
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve it by changing the `log_file`

```
foreach ip [split $file_data "\n"] {
    puts "Router $ip Interface Status"
    spawn telnet $ip

    # Altering 'log_file' for each ip
    log_file -noappend router_${ip}_status.log

    # Your further code here...


}
```

Comment: Its show error message after I have revised router_${ip}_status.txt.----------------cannot start logging without first stopping logging while executing "log_file -noappend router_${ip}_status.txt" ("foreach" body line 4) invoked from within "foreach ip [split $file_data "\n"] { puts "Router $ip Interface Status" spawn telnet $ip log_file -noappend Router_${ip}_status.txt ex..." (file "./intstatus.sh" line 9)

Comment: 4 years and still nobody to answer...I'm stuck in the same place as @Danny Luk.

Comment: RTFM: https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle "cannot start logging without first stopping logging," use "log_file" with no arguments to stop logging, then "log_file path/to/file.log"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).